# Convert data in format [{index:value}] to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have some data in the following format

```
[{'a':1}, {'b':2}, {'c':3}]
```

Is there a way to convert it into a dataframe with {index: value}

```
  value
a  1
b  2
c  3
```

I've tried combinations of the pandas dataframe constructor without success.

- pd.DataFrame()
- pd.DataFrame.from_dict()
- pd.DataFrame.from_records()

Comment: _why_ is your data in that format? It seems like it's either an inappropriate way to store the information (and should be fixed before this step) or, possibly, you might expect the elements of the list (the dicts) to have multiple elements, in which case you probably wont get decent solutions with this trivial example.

Answer (score 0):

A list of dictionaries is not an ideal format to have your data stored for the purpose of creating a Dataframe, but if each dictionary has only one item, you can try the following:

```
data = [{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}, {'c': 3}]
pd.DataFrame(data=[list(x.values())[0] for x in data], index=[list(x.keys())[0] for x in data])
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to convert your data to an appropriate dict format that pandas can understand

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [{'a':1}, {'b':2}, {'c':3}]
data = {k: v for d in data for k, v in d.items()}

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=data, orient='index', columns=['value'])
```

or of course

```py
data = [{'a':1}, {'b':2}, {'c':3}]

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    data={k: v for d in data for k, v in d.items()},
    orient='index', columns=['value']
)
```

Please notice that this only works when you have no duplicate keys among those dicts in your list. If your data looks like the following, then you should consider the solutions provided by @Derek O or @wwnde

```
data = [{'a':1}, {'b':2}, {'c':3}, {'c':4}]
```

Answer (score 0):

tuple and dataframe. Code below

```
pd.DataFrame(tuple(k)).stack().to_frame('Value').droplevel(level=0)



    Value
a    1.0
b    2.0
c    3.0
```